# UML: Missing association between Element and Visitor

Tags: design-patterns, uml

Below is a UML diagram of the [Visitor Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html).

Since `Element.accept()` has a parameter of type `Visitor`, shouldn't there be an association drawn from `Element` to `Visitor`?

[image: UML]

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily.
Remember that UML is not obliged to point out everything. Where possible the diagrams must be kept as simple as possible.
If you think you should note the relationship between Element and Visitor do it.

If we were to point out in a diagram all possible relationships are attribute or parameter between classes instead of pointing the tree would be pointing a forest. ;)
Just UML gives us the versatility and flexibility of drawing to the extent that one needed and necessary.

---

EDIT:
Tomas Kilian, is not a defect of UML.
UML was done well to offer a wide range of possibilities.

As I said, it's not bad; it's not good. It is relative. Everything will depend on the needs you have the developer. Sometimes you have to make explicit the relationship tracing the line and in others not.

Generally the UML diagrams should be kept simple and provide an approximate view to clarify ideas. Because the more you put more complex elements can be done. Obviously, make simple end and almost no nexus or detail take the risk of not capturing the essence.
In the middle is the answer, and it depends on each person. So the best answer I can give is a DEPENDS. This subjectivity is tied to the qualifications and experience of each person.

Answer (score 1):

@Delphius is not necessarily wrong in his statement. However, I would use an association in that case since this simple line makes the relation between the classes much clearer than inspecting the attributes (which you must not show for a compressed view).

So from a practical view: draw the relation.

An association and a typed property are merely two different renderings of the same thing. From my point of view this is so to say a flaw in UML itself. I think the relation should dominate the definition and the property is just a secondary (programming) information. Note that you can also denote it using roles on associations.